# How to set Navigation Drawer to be opened from right to left?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

What are the changes that I need to make in my xml file and java file(given below) so that my navigation drawer opens from right to left? By using the below code my navigation drawer is opening from left to right please do suggest what changes I need to make in my xmml code as well as java code!!!

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#ffff"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.tutecentral.navigationdrawer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
  private ListView mDrawerList;
  private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

  private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
  private CharSequence mTitle;
  CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;

  List<DrawerItem> dataList;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializing
        dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                    GravityCompat.START);

        // Add Drawer Item to dataList
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Message", R.drawable.ic_action_email));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Likes", R.drawable.ic_action_good));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Games", R.drawable.ic_action_gamepad));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Lables", R.drawable.ic_action_labels));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Search", R.drawable.ic_action_search));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Cloud", R.drawable.ic_action_cloud));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Camara", R.drawable.ic_action_camera));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Video", R.drawable.ic_action_video));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Groups", R.drawable.ic_action_group));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Import & Export",
                    R.drawable.ic_action_import_export));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("About", R.drawable.ic_action_about));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Settings", R.drawable.ic_action_settings));
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Help", R.drawable.ic_action_help));

        adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
                    dataList);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                    R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                    R.string.drawer_close) {
              public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                                              // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
              }

              public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                                              // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
              }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
              SelectItem(0);
        }

  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
  }

  public void SelectItem(int possition) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        switch (possition) {
        case 0:
              fragment = new FragmentOne();
              args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 1:
              fragment = new FragmentTwo();
              args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 2:
              fragment = new FragmentThree();
              args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 3:
              fragment = new FragmentOne();
              args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 4:
              fragment = new FragmentTwo();
              args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 5:
              fragment = new FragmentThree();
              args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 6:
              fragment = new FragmentOne();
              args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 7:
              fragment = new FragmentTwo();
              args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 8:
              fragment = new FragmentThree();
              args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 9:
              fragment = new FragmentOne();
              args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 10:
              fragment = new FragmentTwo();
              args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 11:
              fragment = new FragmentThree();
              args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        case 12:
              fragment = new FragmentOne();
              args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getItemName());
              args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                          .getImgResID());
              break;
        default:
              break;
        }

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
        frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
        setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

  }

  @Override
  public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
              return true;
        }

        return false;
  }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
              ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
              SelectItem(position);

        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Change your ListView android:layout_gravity!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set ListView gravity `right` or `end` instead of `start`

```
android:layout_gravity="right"
```

Also update the `DrawerToggle` to :

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
        R.string.drawer_close) {

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                // Notice the Gravity.Right 
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

From [Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#DrawerLayout) :

> The drawer view (the ListView) must specify its horizontal gravity with the android:layout_gravity attribute. To support right-to-left (RTL) languages, specify the value with "start" instead of "left" (so the drawer appears on the right when the layout is RTL).

Comment: I have changed android:layout_gravity="start" to android:layout_gravity="end" but still I am not getting the desired result in my emulator.Do I need to make changes in my java code.

Answer (score 1):

Its as simple as vjdhama said. Adding onto the above you will have to change your ListView to below.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end" //change this, you can also use **right**
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#ffff"/>
```

Also, remember to change the occurence of Gravity.START/ Gravity.LEFT to Gravity.END/ Gravity.Right if you are using it for closing or opening the drawer. Have fun. :)

Comment: I have changed GravityCompat.START to GravityCompat.END and android:layout_gravity="start" to android:layout_gravity="end" but still I am not getting the desired result in my emulator.Do I need to make further changes in my java code.

Comment: Guess you got your answer. :) I had mentioned to replace the same in the code but I mentioned only Gravity.START. :( Have edited it to inclucde Gravity.LEFT as well :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add this action from the button before is open, I found a solution:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
mDrawerToggle = new   ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,toolbar,R.string.openDrawer,R.string.closeDrawer){

@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
}
@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
}
}; // Drawer Toggle Object Made
Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
mDrawerToggle.syncState();               
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (Drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
        Drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
    } else {
        Drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
    }
}
});
```

For more information you can go directly to the link http://ambracode.com/index/show/169202